# What's it called when two people can't decide which way to go?

Tags: single-word-requests

This phenomenon happens to me several times a week and I've actually just recently started pondering if this situation has a defined term for it?

When two people walk towards each other in opposite directions, and they need to quickly decide whether to walk on the right or left side of each other, oftentimes failing to do so when both decide on the same direction, and then switching and causing an awkward situation to occur between you and the stranger. It probably has happened to anyone of you. What is this called?

Answer (score -1):

Believe the word you're looking for is **indecisiveness**.

> Noun   1. indecisiveness - doubt concerning two or more possible alternatives or courses of action; "his indecision was only momentary but the opportunity was lost"

In your case, ** in a moment of indecisiveness** might come to describe the phenomenon most accurately.

Comment: The behavior described is not really a matter of indecisiveness, its the result of two people making wrong decisions with respect to evasive action. When Ive been a participant in such an episode, my usual response is to ask the other party, "shall we dance?"